# Notation for n number of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I have a very basic question about how to denote an arbitrary number of sequences.

For example:

A = $a_1, a_2, ..., a_i$

B = $b_1, b_2, ..., b_j$

and so on. But let's say I have > 26 such sequences. Let's say I  have an arbitrary number of sequences. Normally I would use N/n, but that implies the 14th sequence in this case.

In other words, how can I denote the sequence of sequences: A, B, ..., ? Should I also substitute greek symbols for the indices to avoid using letters redundantly?

THANK YOU!

Comment: You could, for example, denote them as $\{a_j^{(1)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}, \{a_j^{(2)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}, \{a_j^{(3)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+},\dots$, having the superscript (with parentheses to avoid confusion sith exponents) denote the $n$'th sequence $\{a_j^{(n)}\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easiest notation for this type of question is to look sequences as functions $x: \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{R}$ (i.e., points in the space $\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{N}}$). Indeed, if you have an arbitrary collection of sequences $\{x_j: j \in J\}$, then the $j$-th sequence $x_j$ is explicitly
$$
\left(x_j(n): n\in \mathbf{N}\right).
$$
(Note that $J$ is not necessarily a countable set, hence you can index also larger families than "sequences" of sequences.)